# How come I can't use a constructor variable in the rest of my coding?

Tags: java, constructor, jtextpane

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Log extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String logx = "LOG: ";
    JTextPane txt = new JTextPane();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    String addTo;

    public Log() {
        super("LOG");
        setSize(720, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.add(txt);
        add(p);
        txt.setText(logx);
    }

    public Log(String a) {
        addTo = a;
        txt.setText(addTo);

    }
}
```

Here is the coding for my "Log" class,
the idea is that strings from my main class would be displayed in a JTextPane.

I am new to java, so I know using a constructor probably isn't the best way.

How come the String a from my constructor can't be added to my JTextPane?

Please tell me if I didn't give enough information, I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: What error are you getting? I just copied your code to my Eclipse and I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new instance of the Log class and pass it a String (in this case "a"), it will run the code in the `public Log(String a) {` and will not run the `public Log() {` part. You have two different constructors, but only one of them will be called depending on what you pass the class when you create it. Right now, you are trying to set the text of your JTextPane, but you haven't set up the screen (`public Log() {` was never called). In order to fix this, try changing the

```
public Log(String a) {
    addTo = a;
    txt.setText(addTo);

}
```

to

```
public Log(String a) {
    super("LOG");
    setSize(720, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    p.add(txt);
    add(p);
    addTo = a;
    txt.setText(addTo);

}
```

Comment: Or even make one constructor call the other one so you don't have copy-pasted code.

Comment: Just out of curosity, are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: @Steven, Well if you always will send it a string, then there is no use for the first constructor and you can scrap that all together.@Chris, you can't have one constructor call the other one since they are not methods (at least I have never heard of any way to do this).

Answer (score 1):

Does your first constructor work already? If so, try:

```
public Log(String a) {
    super("LOG");
    setSize(720, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    p.add(txt);
    add(p);
    addTo = a;
    txt.setText(addTo);

}
```

It appears your overloaded constructor is missing a few things.